# Unit test if a function takes an argument defined using es6 spread rest object

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, ecmascript-6

I've been trying to write jasmine unit tests to make sure that a function in a module like create() below takes arguments.

```
var Module = function(a, b, c) {
   this.foo = () => { ... };
};

export default {
   create: (...args) => new Module(...args)
};
```

Normally, the arguments 'array' has a length method which will return the number of arguments that the function takes and use .toBe(#). When using the es6 spread / rest object, the length method returns 0.

Is there a way to check a function for the argument length or the existence that it even takes something in this case? I could always just explicitly define each, but this is just one less thing to change between the function caller and the module if things change.

Comment: I don't think `.toBe` uses function length, are you sure? If you use a spread, the function length is the number of arguments before it, there is no way to get around that.

Comment: You should not test whether a function uses a rest parameter. You should test whether it works with taking arbitrary amounts of arguments, regardless whether that is implemented using a rest parameter, the `arguments` object or anything else.

Comment: I agree with Bergi. Do not test implementation specifics. That is just wrong.

Comment: I should've been clearer on the .toBe() part. What I meant is expect(create.length).toBe(3); Regardless, thanks Bergi and naomik. I'm new to unit testing and having issues trying to decide what to test.